# Simulate single big network delay and packet burst after

Tags: networking, sound

I'm testing the Opus codec and VoIP stack which uses it.
I have synthetic test utility which sends internally Opus RTP traffic between two ports on loopback interface + this writes resulting audio to files to allow further analysis.

Using Linux 'tc' utility I can simulate various network impairments.

However I stuck to simulate such thing like "sudden network lag". Sorry for my poor English !

This should look like network is stopped for 1 seconds and after all delayed packets are sent as soon as possible to their targets.

Is it possible to implement with 'tc' utility ?

I tried to run the 'tc' command to make delay 1000ms during the synthetic test process; but it doesn't give me wanted effect.

May anyone to give advice ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Please include the `tc` command you used and describe what "wanted effect" you didn't get from it and did it work for you partially and how or did it not work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This should look like network is stopped for 1 seconds and after all
> delayed packets are sent as soon as possible to their targets.

That is actually possible ... From [`man tc`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/tc.8.html):

> **netem**
> Network Emulator is an enhancement of the Linux  traffic
> control  facilities  that
> allow  to  add  delay,  packet  loss, duplication and more other characteristics to
> packets outgoing from a selected network interface.

... and from [`man tc-netem`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/tc-netem.8.html):

> **slot**
> defer  delivering  accumulated  packets  to  within  a  slot.
> Each  available slot can be    configured with a minimum delay to
> acquire, and an optional maximum delay.

... So, you can do something like this:

```
sudo tc qdisc add dev interface root netem slot 1000ms 1000ms
```

... where `interface` is your intended network interface name as shown in e.g. the output of `ip a`.

That will hold all transmitted packets on the specified interface for `1000ms` and then release them all at once (*in a burst*).

**Notice** that `delay` on the other hand will add a delay of `1000ms` to every transmitted packet on the specified interface.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! You saved my day :)